# Grails UrlMapping - cannot set params.id for controller

Tags: model-view-controller, grails, url-mapping

I'm trying to create a UrlMapping to map some static URL to a controller action, but I can't seem to set `params.id`. I'm working through *Grails in Action*, so I'm not sure what's wrong here.

Code:

```
class UrlMappings
...
static mappings={
    "/timeline/chuck_norris"(controller:'post',action:'timeline',id:'chuck_norris')
...
}
```

**In PostController**

```
def timeline{
   def user = User.findByUserId(params.id)
   [user:user]
}
```

**Error:**
`No signature of method: ...findByUserId() is applicable for argument types: () values: []`

What's wrong with the above code? I'm using grails 1.2.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a closure:

```
"/timeline/chuck_norris"{
            controller = 'post'
            action = 'timeline'
           id = 'chuck_norris"
        }
```

or like this :

```
"/timeline/$id"{
               controller = 'post'
                action = 'timeline'
}
```